# Prove $R$ is transitive $\iff R \circ R \subseteq R $

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> **Proposition.** $R$ is transitive $\iff R \circ R \subseteq R $

My attempt:

$(\rightarrow)$

Suppose $R \subseteq A \times A$ and $R$ is transitive.

Consider arbitrary $(x,y) \in R \circ R$. Implies that there is some $a \in A$, such that $(x,a) \in R$ and  $(a,y) \in R$. By definition of transitivity, we know that $(x,y) \in R$. Arbitrary element was considered, hence $R \circ R \subseteq R$.

$(\leftarrow)$

By contrapositive. Suppose $R$ is not transitive. It follows that there are at least two elements, $(x,y)$ and $(y,p)$, such that both are in $R$. Then $(x,p) \in R \circ R$. But since $R$ is not transitive, $(x,p) \notin R$. Hence $R \circ R \not \subseteq R$.

Is it correct?

Comment: You should reformulate the logic in the second part: "Suppose $R$ is not transitive. It follows that there are three elements $x,y,p$ such that $(x,y)\in R$, $(y,p)\in R$, but $(x,p)\notin R$. Then $(x,p)\in R\circ R$ and hence $R\circ R\not\subseteq R$." -- Better yet, try if you can get rid of the contrapositive and make the second part a direct proof.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  Please, consider converting your comment into the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: This is such a very well written question that it deserves an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If we know $R \circ R \subseteq R$ we can shw transitivity directly:

Suppose $aRb$ and $bRc$ then by definition $a(R \circ R)c$ via $b$, or $(a,c) \in R \circ R$ and so $(a,c) \in R$ (using the inclusion) and so $aRc$ QED.

The contrapositive could work as well. For that you have to assume there are pairs $(a,b), (b,c)\in R$ such that $(a,c) \notin R$ and then we'd also have a contradiction between $(a,c) \in R^2\setminus R$ and $R^2 \subseteq R$. The direct approach is (IMHO) more natural: don't go for a contradiction when you don't need to, and straightforward definitions suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Second part using a direct proof.
Assume $R \circ R \subset R$.
To show transitivity, assume $aRb$ and  $bRc$.
Thus $a(R \circ R)c$, hence $aRc$ showing $R$ is transitive.
I use the usual notation $aRb$ for $(a,b) \in R$.